# submitting arabic data to mysql through form

Tags: php, html, mysql, utf-8, arabic

Hi I am trying to submit arabic data to mysql using forms
I ve already sat up all the columns of tables that should be in arabic to u8_general_ci 
when I save data through phpmyadmin it's well saved and retrieved well but when I submit it through form the data saved as question marks "?????"
although I used 
all of theses

```
        <form  action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" >
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

what could be the solution thanks in advance :)

Comment: This page has some great pointers: http://www.phptherightway.com/#i18n_l10n

Comment: See "question marks" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored . It discusses the likely causes and general Best Practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to set the connection character set, run the following:

```
//PDO example
$dbh->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the HTML5 pattern attribute.

Use this for Arabic : pattern=[أ-يa-zA-Z]

Example:

`<input type="text" name="fname" pattern=[أ-يa-zA-Z] placeholder="Type your name">`

Comment: He did not ask about form validation, this isn't an issue here as well